# passing information between pages in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, code-behind

I need to pass a simple texbox between three pages in Windows Phone 8. Im been searching around, but i dont find it,  i tried this,  'https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx' i have a problem in this method:

```
private void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)

{

    string name = e.NavigationParameter as string;

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
    {
        tb1.Text = "Hello, " + name;
    }
    else
    {
        tb1.Text = "Name is required.  Go back and enter a name.";
    }
}
```

i cant find  LoadStateEventArgs e, missing a using directive or assembly reference.

Comment: What is your problem with this method? Do you get any exception?  You need to be more specific about your problem.

Comment: when i write the method, visual studio says i cant find the namespace name  LoadStateEventArgs e

Comment: Are you writing a Windows 8 or a Windows 8.1 app? Visual Studio 2012 or 2013??

Comment: windows 8.1, visual studio 2013

Comment: hey ! I think I would like to help you ! do you want to pass values from the textbox to multiple pages or what?

Comment: no, i want to pass the value from two differents pages to a third page, that values are textboxes with strings and int values

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly , you want the value stored in the textbox at 3 different pages. Right ?

Check and let me know

```
   // let's assume that you have a simple class:
    public class PassedData
    {
       public string Name { get; set; } //for textBox1
       public string Name1 { get; set; } //for textBox2
       public string Name3 { get; set; } //for textBox3
       public string Name4 { get; set; } //for textBox4
       public string Name5 { get; set; } //for textBox5
       public int Value { get; set; }
    }

//create object of the class like this and asign values to the properties

PassedData abc=new PassedData();
abc.Name=TextBox1.Text;
abc.Name2=TextBox2.Text;
abc.Name3=TextBox3.Text;
abc.Value=TextBox4.Text.ToString();
    // then you navigate like this:
   Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2), abc);

    // and in target Page you retrive the information:
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        PassedData data = e.Parameter as PassedData;
    }
```

Comment: there is a problem, that solution i cannot apply to windows phone 8.1, but yes for the windows phone 7

Comment: i cannot find the navigationservice

Comment: use Frame.Navigate() for windows phone 8.1

Comment: frame.navigate it works, the problem is in pass the information

Comment: ok what information you want to pass ? use lets say that your textxbox1.text data is stored in a string variable by the name Value , pass it to the other page like this ... Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2.Xaml),Value);

Comment: how i can pass the value? im a beginner

Comment: cant you check the solution above ?

Comment: im checking your solution, i have some questions, how i can probe this solution? i want to see the value in the main page, and the second one, when i pass the object in the frame.navigate, im going to do for each textbox?

Comment: see, if you have 5 textboxes on Page1 and you want to pass all  textbox's values to page 2 so what you have to do is to create 5 properties in the class PassedData. there is a way then from where you can pass the whole class to the next page and use it accordingly..let me give you the link

Comment: in this case: Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2), sample); you need to update too, no?

Comment: YES YES ,, IT SHALL BE THE OBJECT abc

Comment: perfect, let me check it out

Comment: cant help more than this :( I hope you found this helpful . If yes please mark this as an answer :)

Comment: did it help @CesarG.Rivas

Comment: i dont find the solution, im trying to do, but i dont get it

Comment: i get this exception: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' in navegacion.exe but not handled in user code.

Comment: i do everything, i create the class, i make the constructor, and the object, the problem is frame navigate

Comment: i did it in the public main page

Comment: searching in in internet i saw a solution, initialize the frame class, its works

Comment: i have another question @apoorv how i can access to the data in the destination page? any variable? its to prove if  it works, pass the data of the page to another

Comment: the code works, but i have a problem passing the int value from the properties to the navigation mode, i have a sintax problem conversion, 'mytext2.ToString = passedData.value',any help?

Comment: i need a solution please

Comment: I have updated my answer for the Integer value.... we are passing the interger as a string first and then converting it back to Integer on the next page.... do this on the Navigated Page .lets says int RollNumber is the parameter on the navigated page , to assign Value to RollNumber do this .. RollNumberConvert.ToInt32(PassedData.Value) ;

Comment: doesnt work, the compiler says, You can not convert implicitly string type in int.

Comment: i tryed to do this tb3.Text = nav.value.ToString(); it passed a value of cero, i dont know

Comment: it the code running for other values except integers ?

Comment: i found a solution, its works, when i passed the value, its a integer, but in the destination page, convert to string and assing the value to a tb3.text, it works thanks

Comment: @CesarG.Rivas   if you find the solution helpful , please mark the answer :)

Comment: 'passing the info:

 navigation nav = new navigation();
            {
                nav.name = tb1.Text;
                nav.value = int.Parse(tb3.Text);
            };
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(pagina1),nav);
        
the destination page:
 var nav = (navigation)e.Parameter;
            
            mytext1.Text = nav.name;
            mytext2.Text = nav.value.ToString();
            text2.Text = nave.value2.ToString();


the class navigation:
 public class navigation
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int value { get; set; }
}'

Comment: i have another problem, when i try to pass data of one page, i pass very well, but when i try to pass data between more pages i have this problem System.InvalidCastException, any help? i use the same public class and method of you example

Comment: i have this problem when i try to navigate between pages, if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

Comment: There is something that you r doing wrong. The program is breaking at compilation . I am sorry to say I could only assist till this level. Here you have to try on your own we can't spoonfeed u

Comment: thanks @apoorv i dont know to do, let me check my code

Comment: i found my problem, im using the microsoft band method in the main page,  i have this error global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
when i try to navigate from one page to the main page where works the microsoft band in the event handler and it button, i dont kow how fix it

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't concentrate too much on the data you pass, but rather on the data model that is the backbone of your App. There should be a data model class containing the text content you want to store. The instance of this class should "survive" any page, so if you have one page that writes to this property, then you can have another page displaying the value of this field. You should also consider creating a view model for each page, which serves as glue code for transferring the property value between model and page, and can also help if you have type conversion, data validation, mandatory fields etc.

Comment: tanks, let me try it